# Azure Mobile Services Scripts triggering

Tags: .net, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

so I know there is no HTTP API for mobile services push notifications mechanism, my only hope is I can use push notifications from a script, however I want to know if the script triggers even if not inserted from a mobile client sdk, let's say I insert data to the database from a .NET server, will it trigger my script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insert the data using the Azure Mobile Service REST interface (i.e., by making a HTTP call to `https://your-service.azure-mobile.net/tables/your-table-name`), then yes, the scripts will be called. If you insert the data directly to the SQL Azure database, then no, the script will not be called.